# Parse ISO 8601 both basic and extended format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601, datetime-parsing

As far as I see the the DateTime.ParseExact with "o" and "s" parameters is capable of parsing ISO 8601 extended format only.

How do I parse ISO 8601 both basic and extended formats using c#/.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the class that I finally created to parse both basic and extended formats:

```
static class Iso8601Formats
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 extended time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] TimeExtended;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 basic time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] TimeBasic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 both basic and extended time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] Time;


    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 extended date format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateExtended;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 basic date format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateBasic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 both basic and extended time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] Date;


    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 extended date and time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateAndTimeExtended;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 basic date and time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateAndTimeBasic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 both basic and extended date and time format.
    /// </summary>        
    public static readonly string[] DateAndTime;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 extended date and/or time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateAndOrTimeExtended;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 basic date and/or time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateAndOrTimeBasic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents ISO 8601 both basic and extended date and/or time format.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string[] DateAndOrTime;

    static Iso8601Formats()
    {
        // date format extended
        IList<string> dateExtended = new List<string>{
                                      "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"  // 1985-04-12
                                  };
        DateExtended = dateExtended.ToArray();

        // date format basic
        IList<string> dateBasic = new List<string>{
                                      "yyyyMMdd"        // 19850412
                                      ,"yyyy'-'MM"      // 1985-04
                                      ,"yyyy"           // 1985
                                      ,"'--'MMdd"       // --0412
                                      ,"'---'dd"        // ---12
                                  };
        DateBasic = dateBasic.ToArray();

        // date both basic and extended format
        List<string> date = new List<string>();
        date.AddRange(dateBasic);
        date.AddRange(dateExtended);
        Date = date.ToArray();


        // time format extended
        IList<string> timeExtended = new List<string>{                                          
                                      "HH':'mm':'sszzz"       // 10:22:00-0800
                                      ,"HH':'mm':'sszz"       // 10:22:00-08
                                      ,"HH':'mm':'ssZ"        // 10:22:00Z
                                      ,"HH':'mm':'ss"         // 10:22:05
                                      ,"HH':'mm"              // 10:22
                                      ,"HH"                   // 10
                                      ,"'-:'mm':'ss"          // -22:07
                                      ,"'-:-:'ss"             // -:-:07
        };
        TimeExtended = timeExtended.ToArray();

        // time format basic
        IList<string> timeBasic = new List<string>{                                          
                                      "HHmmsszzz"       // 102200-0800
                                      ,"HHmmsszz"       // 102200-08
                                      ,"HHmmssZ"        // 102200Z
                                      ,"HHmmss"         // 102205
                                      ,"HHmm"           // 1022
                                      ,"HH"             // 10
                                      ,"'-'mmss"        // -2207
                                      ,"'--'ss"         // --07
                                  };
        TimeBasic = timeBasic.ToArray();


        // time format both basic and extended
        List<string> time = new List<string>();
        time.AddRange(timeBasic);
        time.AddRange(timeExtended);
        Time = time.ToArray();


        // date-time basic
        IList<string> dateTimeBasic = 
            CombineFormats(dateBasic, timeBasic);
        DateAndTimeBasic = dateTimeBasic.ToArray();

        // date-time extended
        IList<string> dateTimeExtended = 
            CombineFormats(dateExtended, timeExtended);
        DateAndTimeExtended = dateTimeExtended.ToArray();

        // date-time both basic and extended
        List<string> dateTime = new List<string>();
        dateTime.AddRange(dateTimeBasic);
        dateTime.AddRange(dateTimeExtended);
        DateAndTime = dateTime.ToArray();


        // date-and-or-time basic format
        List<string> dateAndOrTimeBasic = new List<string>();
        dateAndOrTimeBasic.AddRange(dateTimeBasic);
        dateAndOrTimeBasic.AddRange(dateBasic);
        foreach (string timeFormat in timeBasic)
        {
            dateAndOrTimeBasic.Add("'T'" + timeFormat);
        }
        DateAndOrTimeBasic = dateAndOrTimeBasic.ToArray();

        // date-and-or-time extended format
        List<string> dateAndOrTimeExtended = new List<string>();
        dateAndOrTimeExtended.AddRange(dateTimeExtended);
        dateAndOrTimeExtended.AddRange(dateExtended);
        foreach (string timeFormat in timeExtended)
        {
            dateAndOrTimeExtended.Add("'T'" + timeFormat);
        }
        DateAndOrTimeExtended = dateAndOrTimeExtended.ToArray();


        // date-and-or-time basic and extended format
        List<string> dateAndOrTime = new List<string>();
        dateAndOrTime.AddRange(dateAndOrTimeBasic);
        dateAndOrTime.AddRange(dateAndOrTimeExtended);
        DateAndOrTime = dateAndOrTime.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Produces all combinations of date and time formats
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dates">List of dates formats</param>
    /// <param name="times">List of time formats</param>
    private static IList<string> CombineFormats(IList<string> dates, IList<string> times)
    {
        List<string> dt = new List<string>();
        foreach (string dateFormat in dates)
        {
            foreach (string timeFormat in times)
            {
                // year/month must be present if time zone is specified
                if (dateFormat.StartsWith("'-") && (timeFormat.IndexOfAny(new[] { 'z', 'Z' }) != -1))
                    continue;

                dt.Add(dateFormat + "'T'" + timeFormat);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

The **Iso8601Formats.DateAndOrTime** static property is probably the most useful in this class. Using the code:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("1985-04-12T10:22:00Z", Iso8601Formats.DateAndOrTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I was able to parse the following ISO 8601 date/times:

```
19850412
1985-04
1985
--0412
---12
1985-04-12
T102205
T1022
T10
T-2207
T--07
T102200Z
T102200-08
T102200-0830
T10:22:05
T10:22
T10
T-:22:07
T-:-:07
T10:22:00Z
T10:22:00-08
T10:22:00-0830
19850412T102205
19850412T1022
19850412T10
19850412T-2207
19850412T--07
19850412T102200Z
19850412T102200-08
19850412T102200-0830
1985-04T102205
1985-04T1022
1985-04T10
1985-04T-2207
1985-04T--07
1985-04T102200Z
1985-04T102200-08
1985-04T102200-0830
1985T102205
1985T1022
1985T10
1985T-2207
1985T--07
1985T102200Z
1985T102200-08
1985T102200-0830
--0412T102205
--0412T1022
--0412T10
--0412T-2207
--0412T--07
---12T102205
---12T1022
---12T10
---12T-2207
---12T--07
1985-04-12T10:22:05
1985-04-12T10:22
1985-04-12T10
1985-04-12T-:22:07
1985-04-12T-:-:07
1985-04-12T10:22:00Z
1985-04-12T10:22:00-08
1985-04-12T10:22:00-0830
```

This class however is still unable to parse date/times with a time zone specified and year absent, such as:

```
--0412T102200Z
--0412T102200-08
--0412T102200-0830
```

Comment: Some constructive criticism:  1) This class may achieve what you set out to do, but it is fairly inefficient.  Since the net result is always the same, you might as well just have some constants in a static class. 2) Why are you looking to parse so many different inputs into one result?  You may get *some* result but one would ask for a particular input for a particular purpose.  For example, if someone provides only `"T10:22:07"`, the result may have that time, but it also has today's date, and the local machine's offset.  You can't just treat it as a `DateTimeOffset` at that point,

Comment: you'd want to only look at the time components, but you would have now way of knowing that.  3)  If you plan to do anything complex like this, you may just want to look to [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) instead.  There are a lot of nuances like these that will trap you.  Noda Time forces you down a path that avoids the traps.  4)  Good luck!

Comment: I need to parse so many types of date/time formats because this is what is specified by vCard RFC 6350 and RFC 2426 that I need to implement. The field that I am parsing can be date or time or date+time in basic or in extended formats.

Comment: Thank you for the nodatime reference. I quickly looked at it, looks like it supports a single extended format only: http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/offsetdatetime-patterns.html

Comment: Yes, you can make all these date and time formatters fields constant. But the initialization arrays will be pretty big (64 for DateAndOrTime only). There will be tonnes of duplicates, it will be fairly difficult to support such class. Adding a support for just a single new format will require changes in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass an array of the formats you wish to allow.

```
string[] formats = new[] {"o","s","yyyyMMddHHmmss"}; // whatever you want
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, formats,
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStlyes.None);
```